# How to combine multiple named patterns into one Cases?

Tags: pattern-matching

In this toy example,

```
lis = {C[1]*3, C[2]*9, 123};
```

I want to change, using Cases, the pattern  `C[x__]*y_` to `C[x]*99*y` and the pattten `y_Integer` to `5*y`

Currently I do it using two separate calls and then use Join on the result. Like this

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
lis = {C[1]*3, C[2]*9, 123};
c1 = Cases[lis, C[x__]*y_ :> C[x]*99*y]
c2 = Cases[lis, y_Integer :> 5*y]
Join[c1, c2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is it possible to do it using just one call to Cases?

```
Cases[lis, ??? ]
```

Not able to find what the syntax could be (if it is even possible).

`Alternative` does not do what I want (at least I could not make it work).

Ofcourse this should extend to more than just two, it should work with 3 different patterns and 4 and as many as one wants.

**Update**

The above toy example may be was too toy.  Here is another example

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
lis = {Sin[x], Cos[x], 99, x};
c1 = Cases[lis, Sin[x_] :> 3 + Sin[2*x]]
c2 = Cases[lis, Cos[x_] :> Exp[x]*Tan[x]]
c3 = Cases[lis, x_Integer :> Integrate[x, z]]
Join[c1, c2, c3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The idea to keep the same patterns used for each case, but combine them into one call to Cases. I do not want to change the logic or anything like that. In a new universe, I'd like to do for the above this

```
Cases[lis, Sin[x_] :> 3 + Sin[2*x] | 
           Cos[x_] :> Exp[x]*Tan[x]] |
           x_Integer :> Integrate[x, z]
     ]
```

But the above ofcourse does not work.

Comment: `Cases[lis, a_. * y_Integer :> a*99*y, 1]`

Comment: @BobHanlon  I think I put an example which makes yours work. the `99` is not meant to be the same. It can be anything for each pattern. I will correct my example to make it general. The patterns have nothing in common in practice.

Comment: For this input `Cases[lis, y_ :> If[FreeQ[y, C], 5*y, 99*y], 1]` If non-integers can occur, add an additional test.

Comment: @BobHanlon humm... thanks, but I do not think I am making my example general enough. The idea to use same pattern(s) in those separate Cases, in one case. I will make a new example, where what you are suggesting might not be practical? I simply want to combine the patterns used in the separate calls,  into one call (if that is possible).

Comment: btw @BobHanlon do you see anything wrong with how I did the workaround above, which is to simply make separate call to Cases and then join the results? If no, I could just keeping doing that. I was just wondering if there is a way to combine them into one call, that is all.

Comment: I would probably use `Join[Cases[lis, #][[1]] & /@ {Sin[x_] :> 3 + Sin[2*x], Cos[x_] :> Exp[x]*Tan[x], x_Integer :> Integrate[x, z]}]`

Comment: `cases = {c1, c2, c3};` and `NestList[Cases[lis, #] &, cases, Length@cases] // Flatten`  ?

Comment: You can use `Replace` with your list of patterns + a falling pattern to remove them at the end like `_ -> Nothing`, Example 1: `Replace[lis, {C[x__]*y_ :> C[x]*99*y, y_Integer :> 5*y, _ -> Nothing}, {1}]`, Example 2: `Replace[lis, {Sin[x_] :> 3 + Sin[2*x], Cos[x_] :> Exp[x]*Tan[x], x_Integer :> Integrate[x, z], _ -> Nothing}, {1}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Why (*I think*) it doesn't work?

The problem with the proposed solution is (*probably*) that [*`Cases`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) needs its **second** argument to be a *pattern* (or a pattern [*`Rule`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html)-or [*`RuleDelayed`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) which is kind of the *same* thing, for our purposes here- something like **eg.** `x_:>f[x]`); however, the proposed solution (where the question is driving at), uses a *list* of patterns, instead. We all know, that a *list* of patterns is not (*necessarily*?) a *pattern* itself.

Therefore, it should come as no surprise when something like this doesn't perform as expected:

```
(* input *)
lis = {Sin[x], Cos[x], 99, x};
rls = {Sin[x_] :> 3 + Sin[2*x], Cos[x_] :> Exp[x]*Tan[x], x_Integer :> Integrate[x, z]};

(* evaluation *)
Cases[lis, rls]
```

(it evaluates to `{}`, which is not what one expected to get.)

### 1.1 What would be a possible solution?

Seeing as having a second argument to `Cases` that is not a pattern, is (or, might be) the problem, one possible solution, would be to transform the *list* of pattern rules into a pattern itself; one way to achieve this is by using [*`Alternatives`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html):

```
patt = p : Alternatives @@ rls[[All, 1]]
Cases[lis, patt :> sel[p]]
```

Now, `sel[p]` is a function we need to define, which will accept as an argument, the *matched* left-hand-side of a target pattern and will produce the desired right-hand-side of that pattern, eg. `sel[Sin[x]]` should produce `3+Sin[2x]` etc.

This is a possible solution, however it will not be pursued further in this note of an answer because it suggests a path where at some point the user will *have* to define `sel[p]` *for all* admissible/desirable patterns in their input and that seems (it might possibly not be the case, however it feels like that at the present moment of writing) cumbersome.

### 2. What could possibly work?

One possible solution, which, however, needs to *repeatedly* apply `Cases` (here, using  `Fold`) on the list of pattern rules, is the following:

```
rls // cases[lis]
```

which evaluates to

```
{3+Sin[2 x], E^x Tan[x], 99 z}
```

---

The code

```
(* case is expected to work with a single pattern rule *)
case[list_] := (Cases[list, #] &);
(* join will combine a previous result with the current output of case *)
join[list_] := (Join[#1, case[list][#2]] &);
(* fold will apply join on a list of arguments (pattern rules) *)
fold[list_] := (Fold[join[list], ##] &);
(* doFold simply applies fold on an appropriate list of pattern rules *)
doFold[list_] := Apply[fold[list]];

(* init prepares a list of pattern rules {p1,p2,...,pn} into {{p1}, {p2,...,pn}} *)
init = (TakeDrop[#, 1] &);

(* mapAt initializes the first element in the fold *)
mapAt[list_] := (MapAt[Apply[case[list]], #, 1] &);

(* cases combines all the previous steps in one function *)
cases[list_] := init/*mapAt[list]/*doFold[list]
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all the input and comments.

I thought to share a solution I came up with. What I really wanted is to apply a set of patterns on input, and have those expressions in the input which match the pattern be transformed, and those that do not match any pattern to remain the same.

`Cases` does not allow one to do it all at once. This solution below uses `Scan` to scan the input one item at a time, and for each item, it uses `MatchQ` on each rule collecting all matched hits. If no hit, then the item remains as is.

Here are few example usage. In all example the setup is the same. We define the `input` and the `rules`, and it does the rest

### Example 1

```
input = {C[1]*3, C[2]*9, 123};
rules = {C[x__]*y_ :> C[x]*99*y, y_Integer :> 5*y};

Flatten@Last@Reap@Scan[Sow@process[#, rules] &, input]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Example 2

```
input = {Sin[x], Cos[x], 99, x};
rules = {Sin[x_] :> 3 + Sin[2*x], Cos[x_] :> Exp[x]*Tan[x], x_Integer :> Integrate[x, z]};

Flatten@Last@Reap@Scan[Sow@process[#, rules] &, input]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Example 3

```
input = {Sin[x], Cos[x], 9, x, Pi};
rules = {Sin[x_] :> 3 + Sin[2*x], Cos[x_] :> Exp[x]*Tan[x], x_Integer :> x^2};
Flatten@Last@Reap@Scan[Sow@process[#, rules] &, input]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Code V 0.1 beta

```
process[item_, rules_] := Module[{n, matchFound = False, result},
  result = Last@Reap@Do[
      If[ MatchQ[item, First@rules[[n]]],
       Sow[item /. rules[[n]]];
       matchFound = True;
       ], {n, Length[rules]}
      ];
  If[Not[matchFound], result = item];
  result
  ]
```

Comment: (+1) Although it doesn't answer your question, `Through[(Cases/@rules)[input]]//Flatten` as a possible 'workaround'?

Comment: @user1066  yes, it is a workaround, because Cases does not allow one to having multiple named patterns each with its own :>. But your workaround does not do that I really wanted, which is to also keep terms which do not match any rule, remain as is.  Compare ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RreL.png)  with ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly7Di.png). But thanks for your works. I know I did not mention that I want to keep terms that do not change in the output. This was something I found is useful later on.

Comment: Ok, and if that is the case (you want to keep terms that do not match any rules), I have certainly misinterpreted the question. But if so, why not use `Replace`?  For example, `Replace[input2, rules2, {1}]` . I am probably still misinterpreting your question.

Comment: `input2={Sin[x],Cos[x],9, x, Pi}` and `rules2={Sin[x_] :> 3 + Sin[2*x],Cos[x_] :> Exp[x]*Tan[x],x_Integer :> x^2}`

Comment: @user1066 because I did not think of using Replace directly, I used it inside the process function when MatchQ is true. But your's is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[foo]

foo = Function[, 
   alt : Alternatives @@ #[[All, 1]] :> ReplaceAll[#] @ alt, 
   HoldFirst] ;
```

***Examples:***

```
input1 = {C[1]*3, C[2]*9, 123};
rules1 = {C[x__]*y_ :> C[x]*99*y, y_Integer :> 5*y};

Cases[input1, foo @ rules1]
```

> ```
> {297 C[1], 891 C[2], 615}
> ```

```
input2 = {Sin[x], Cos[x], 99, x};
rules2 = {Sin[x_] :> 3 + Sin[2*x],
    Cos[x_] :> Exp[x]*Tan[x], 
    x_Integer :> Integrate[x, z]};

Cases[input2, foo @ rules2]
```

> ```
> {3 + Sin[2 x], E^x Tan[x], 99 z}
> ```

```
input3 = {Sin[x], Cos[x], 9, x, Pi};
rules3 = {Sin[x_] :> 3 + Sin[2*x], 
    Cos[x_] :> Exp[x]*Tan[x], 
    x_Integer :> x^2};

Cases[input3, foo @ rules3]
```

> ```
> {3 + Sin[2 x], E^x Tan[x], 81}
> ```